# SSL SOAP : IBM SOAP Server Application doesn't let me use the hosted web service

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

At work I am currently programming an app which sends an XML file to a web service. What does my service do with it doesn't matter, that is how he gets that matters.

Before going on this project, I was really new to SOAP and SSL encryption.

It took me a little a bit more than a dozen of hours to figure what to do exactly in order to get a response from the Web Service with PHP and its SOAP API.

I have finally got a contact with the service but there is an obscure security issue that I have met and still meeting.

Here is the error :

```
soapenv:Serversecurity.wssecurity.WSSContextImpl.s02: com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException: Exception org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: CWWSS7200E: Unable to create AxisService from ServiceEndpointAddress : http://example.com/webservice/ ocurred while running action: com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler$1@6bd36bd3
```

Edit :

And some additional informations on the transaction.

> Request header :
>   POST /example.com/webservice HTTP/1.1 Host: example.com Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.4.39-0+deb7u1 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 SOAPAction: "" Content-Length: 231
>
> Request body :
>
> Reponse header :
>   HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Connection: close Date: Mon, 29 Aug 2016 14:19:02 GMT Server: Gateway Set-Cookie: BIGipServer~extranet~P_P1_VSP1=763381288.37012.0000; Path=/; Via: Gateway X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Content-Language: fr-FR Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
>
> Reponse Body :
>   soapenv:Serversecurity.wssecurity.WSSContextImpl.s02: com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException: Exception org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: CWWSS7200E: Impossible de créer AxisService à partir de ServiceEndpointAddress : http://example.com/web_service ocurred while running action: com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler$1@5d4a5d4a

What is weird is that the request that I send is empty. How could it be ?

On the [IBM website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM79653) it is written that it occurs

> *when there is non UTF-8              ServiceEndpointAddress*

I don't really catch the meaning of it, first because I am a french native, and second because I'm really new to Web Services programming.

As you will see in my code, the character encryption of the sended XML is declared 'utf-8'. I have also tried to encode the content of my file with **utf8_encode()** from PHP before sending : nothing new on the screen.

Here is the PHP Code that realizes the connexion to the Web Service :

```
  $filename = "test1.xml";
  $XMLStr = file_get_contents("test1.xml");
  $wsdl    = $wsdl_url;
  $options = Array();
  $options[ 'local_cert' ] = $pem_file;
  $options[ 'location' ] = $server_location;
  $options[ 'uri' ] = $namespace_file;
  $options[ 'soap_version' ] = SOAP_1_1;
  $options[ 'trace' ] = true;
  $options[ 'encoding' ] = 'utf-8';

  try {
     $soapCli = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
     $soapCli->traitementFlux($XMLStr);
  } catch(SoapFault $e)
  {
     echo 'Error['.$e->faultcode.'] : '.$e->faultstring.'<br/>';
     echo '<br/><br/>'.$soapCli->__getLastResponse().'<br/>';
  }
```

I don't have any rights on the server.

Is there a bug or a feature misunderstanding ?

Thanks for future answers.